# crystal report group by

Tags: crystal-reports, group-by

Is there any way to print Group N of M (like page N of M)in Crystal report ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Create a new formula and use the `GroupNumber` function.  It's in the `Print State` section.  Also take a look at the `GroupingLevel(fld)` function under `Document Properties` to see if it meets your needs better.

Comment: Could you please explain. If the report have 5 groups, I want to show in group1  "1 of 5", in group2 "2 of 5" etc.

Comment: Create a new formula, named groupNumber.  Have the formula return the groupNumber value.  You'll find the groupNumber function in the list of Crystal functions in the Print State section, or refer to the Help files.  In your report, use the new function value appended to the static text " of 5"